# How to fire an event immediately?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm binding an event like this, using prototype js:

```
$('country').observe('change',function(e) { ... });
```

How can I fire it once immediately?

in jQuery, I'd just tack on a `.triggerHandler('change')`. Is there something similar in prototype?

Comment: what do you mean by immediately? as soon as the page loads?

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: No. Immediately immediately. As in, when that line of code is hit. It's below the HTML element, so I know it exists already.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `load` event. Something like this:

```
// calls addListeners when the document loads
Event.observe(window, 'load', addListeners, false); 

function addListeners() {   

    // called onLoad
    fireOnce();

    // observer for the country dropdown
    $('country').observe('change', function(event) {
        fireOnChange();
    });
}

function fireOnce() {
    // do something
}

function fireOnChange() {
    // do something
}
```

When the document loads, `fireOnce()` will execute. I use this technique all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If using an extension is an option, I have had success in the past with [event.simulate](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js) for this purpose.

It'll allow you to do something like:

```
$('country').simulate('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var handler = function(e) {...};
$("country").observe("change",handler);
handler();
```

---

Alternatively (less readable, avoids temporary variable):

```
$("country").observe("change",(function(e) { ... return arguments.callee;})());
```

---

However, in both cases you will not be able to use `this` as you might expect. This solution is better suited to more general callbacks such as for `setInterval`

Comment: i'm presently using the former method... `arguments.callee` is deprecated, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

...if you know that it exists, and you know that you're not waiting for pageload or waiting for a script to load, why not just:

```
(function (el) {
    if (!el) { return; }
    doSomething(el);
}(document.getElementById("country")));
```

Comment: that will fire it once and only once..where's the change event?

Comment: @Mark Add it afterward -- or include this call inside of your definition of the function.  You are looking to do two things: 1) initialize your code and append a listener. 2) handle subsequent changes  So treat it that way.  Even if that means defining a `handleChange` function, then attaching a `change` listener to your object, and then automatically calling the `handleChange` functionality the first time, using the pattern I wrote out.  Then you don't have to scratch your head trying to shoehorn initialization-handling into your generic listener, and vice versa.